# udev GROUP and MODE assignments on symbolic link have no effect

Tags: permissions, usb, symlink, udev

I'm trying to connect my velleman k8055 board per usb to my pc.
For this I have the udev rule

```
SUBSYSTEM !="usb_device", ACTION !="add", GOTO="velleman_rules_end"

ATTRS{idVendor}=="10cf", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5500", MODE="0660", GROUP="k8055", SYMLINK+="k8055_0"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="10cf", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5501", MODE="0660", GROUP="k8055", SYMLINK+="k8055_1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="10cf", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5502", MODE="0660", GROUP="k8055", SYMLINK+="k8055_2"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="10cf", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5503", MODE="0660", GROUP="k8055", SYMLINK+="k8055_3"

LABEL="velleman_rules_end"
```

from [jeremyz's k8055 github repo](https://github.com/jeremyz/k8055/velleman.rules).

After plugging the board in, I even get the k8055_0 symlink, but it's rights are root:root.

But I want that users from the group k8055 can access this link (which is not possible with root:root permissions).

Comment: See this Q&A on AU: http://askubuntu.com/questions/175245/udev-not-updating-usb-permissions-and-group

Comment: @slm Thanks!
But in what way does this help me?
The answer just gives a solution that works, but not why.
And the three points with explanations do not suit my case, as I either do not have the described problem (e.g. conflicts/rule not workingat all) or I already have the solution (e.g. symlink).

Comment: It's a similar problem that I thought might help you out since that example is purported to work, in the sense that it will create devices that users in groupX can access. I that not your problem? Perhaps you should revise your Q since that's what it reads as in it's current form!

Comment: I don't have much experience with `udev` so I don't know if it would compensate for this but symlinks usually have immutably wide-open permissions so that permissions end up being set at the hard link you're pointing toward and not any number of links you may forget to update later if permissions need to change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GROUP and MODE do have an effect. They affect the device node, not the symbolic link.

Linux doesn't support permissions on symbolic links. All symbolic links are world-readable and cannot be written to (only overwritten by a new link). So it doesn't matter that the symbolic link belongs to root: other users can access it anyway.

Since the device node has the group and permissions you specify, you are getting the desired access control. Users in the `k8055` group can access the device (via the symlink or directly); users outside that group can see where the symbolic link points to but then cannot access the device.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am searching for official document on this, Can you please share ?

Comment: @monty024 Official documentation on what? The udev documentation describes what GROUP and MODE do. For the fact that Linux doesn't support permissions on symbolic links, the `chmod(2)` man page states “AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW — If pathname is a symbolic link, do not dereference it: instead operate on the link itself. This flag is not currently implemented.” If it's how access permissions work, read a basic textbook on Unix, or if you want something official read the POSIX specification.

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect.   Linux does support permissions on symlinks, they just don't do much.  But some external utilities check them (like samba and apache) and may refuse to use symlinks with wrong owner/group.

Comment: @user10489 Most Linux _filesystems_ don't support setting the permission bits on a symlink. Most Linux tools (e.g. `chmod`) don't support setting the permission bits on a symlink. The Linux kernel ignores the permission bits when traversing a symbolic link. So while “Linux doesn't support permissions on symbolic links” isn't completely accurate, it's closer to the truth than “Linux supports permissions on symbolic links”. And the lack of support is what's relevant in this threda.

Comment: Most linux filesystems and unixes in general don't support permission *bits* on symlinks, but all the ones I've tested certainly support owner and group permissions.  And best as I can tell, udev does not supply a way to change these.  Although I'm not sure anything checks.